# Create a list representing the inventory of products in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, list

I have a programming assignment but I cannot figure out how to fix this output problem.

This is my output:

```
[['Choc 5\t'], ['Vani 10'], ['Stra 7'], ['Choc 3 '], ['Stra 4']]
```

But it should be like this:

```
['Choc', 5], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 7], ['Choc', 3], ['Stra', 4]]
```

Code:

```
def process_input(lst):
    result = list(map(lambda x: [x[0:7]], lst))
    return result

string = input()
lines = []
while string != "END":
    lines.append(string)
    string = input()
print(process_input(lines))
```

Comment: Please give an example of an string used for `string = input()`

Answer (score 0):

```
output = [['Choc 5\t'], ['Vani 10'], ['Stra 7'], ['Choc 3 '], ['Stra 4']]
print(output)
output = [[s[0].strip().split(' ')[0], int(s[0].strip().split(' ')[1])] for s in a]
print(output)
```

output

```
[['Choc 5\t'], ['Vani 10'], ['Stra 7'], ['Choc 3 '], ['Stra 4']]
[['Choc', 5], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 7], ['Choc', 3], ['Stra', 4]]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try this approach :

```
data=[['Choc 5\t'], ['Vani 10'], ['Stra 7'], ['Choc 3 '], ['Stra 4']]

print(list(map(lambda x:[x[0].split()[0] , int(x[0].split()[1])],data)))
```

output:

```
[['Choc', 5], ['Vani', 10], ['Stra', 7], ['Choc', 3], ['Stra', 4]]
```